# check if certain word exists in div

Tags: javascript

I was just wondering if there would be away i can check if a last div with same class name contains a certain word and if the certain word exists run a function.

every time i tried to search for help all i find is all in jquery

```js
var words =  #hey, #join, #slap
var nodes = document.querySelectorAll('.hud-chat-message');
var last = nodes[nodes.length- 1];

// Check for certain words here in nodes last
```

```html
<div id="hud-chat" class="hud-chat">
  <div class="hud-chat-message">
    <strong>Name</strong>: text here
  </div>
  <div class="hud-chat-message">
    <strong>Name</strong>: text here
  </div>
  <div class="hud-chat-message">
    <strong>Name</strong>: just more text here
  </div>
  <div class="hud-chat-message">
    <strong>Name</strong>: text here
  </div>
  <div class="hud-chat-message">
    <strong>Name</strong>: /join
  </div>
  <div class="hud-chat-message">
    <strong>Name</strong>: text here
  </div>
  <div class="hud-chat-message">
    <strong>Name</strong>: /slap
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm afraid it's not clear whether you're asking how to tell *whether* `last` contains a word, or how to find the last div with that class that does...? (And in your example, what word are you looking for?)

Comment: i want to know if i can check if last contains certain word can this be done?

Comment: Of course you can. You get the text (from [`textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent), [`innerText`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/innerText), or [`innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML)) and then look to see if the word is in that text.

Comment: Question was closed before i could answer: https://jsbin.com/suciweminu/edit?html,js,console,output

Here you got!

Comment: [`const found = words.some(word => node.textContent.includes(word));`](https://jsfiddle.net/smu39kx1/1/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this. The words should be an array containing all the words. Then you simply iterate over the words and check if they are part of the string using `indexOf`.

```js
var words =  ['hey', 'join', 'slap'];
var nodes = document.querySelectorAll('.hud-chat-message');
var last = nodes[nodes.length- 1];

for(var i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
  if(last.innerText.indexOf(words[i]) > -1) {
    console.log('Found: ' + words[i]);
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="hud-chat" class="hud-chat">
<div class="hud-chat-message"><strong>Name</strong>: text here</div>
<div class="hud-chat-message"><strong>Name</strong>: text here</div>
<div class="hud-chat-message"><strong>Name</strong>: just more text here</div>
<div class="hud-chat-message"><strong>Name</strong>: text here</div>
<div class="hud-chat-message"><strong>Name</strong>: /join</div>
<div class="hud-chat-message"><strong>Name</strong>: text here</div>
<div class="hud-chat-message"><strong>Name</strong>: /slap</div>
</div>
```

Comment: wow this is just what i was looking for and it worked ! thank you for your help